# How to make a H1 tag look like this

Tags: html, css

i was developing a certain web page when i came across a issue.

```
 <h1 class="h-padrao">SECRETARIAS</h1>
```

is it possible to make a h1,h2,h3 tags look like this using only css and html (no images)?

[image]

i tried to do this using :after but i achieved no success

thanks

Comment: Help us to help you. Tell us what you've already tried **and why it didn't work or what results you got instead**.

Comment: This should be easily adaptable: http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Comment: @CBroe You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the fun,

More like a trick with `text-shadow` and `background`: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wItAd

```
h1 {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to left,transparent 0px, transparent 1px, black 1px, black 2px) center repeat-x;
  background-size:2px 2px;
  text-shadow:
    0 0 20px white, 
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    0 0 20px white,
    10px 0 white
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does not have an overflow problem: http://jsfiddle.net/functionalcss/gbu3ghr5/.

HTML:

```
<h1 class = "dotted-line">functionalcss.com</h1>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.dotted-line {
    font: normal 20px/1 Sans-Serif;
    color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
}

.dotted-line:first-line {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff;
}

.dotted-line:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off of @CBRoe's suggestion, you could do something like this:

```
h1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qoqub87/)

Comment: Although you'd probably not want to do this on *all* h1 elements

Comment: ^True. If you only want this to be applied to some `h1` elements, you will want to add a class to those elements and modify the CSS to target that specific class. I.E. `.h-padrao:after {}`

Comment: The solution is not perfect, because it makes the h1 overflow its container.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h1>SECRETARIAS<span></span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #656565;
    font-size: 14px;
}
h1 span:before  {
    content: "------------------------------------------ " ;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be very reusable